# git push not updating remote branch

Tags: git

I am doing this command with git:

```
git push origin mybranch
```

It keeps saying "Every up to date" but nothing happened on the server side. I think I did something wrong before but I am not sure where:

Yesterday I did a commit with a commit number [c1] and pushed the commit to server. Then I tried to pull the update from another developer:

```
git pull origin another
```

Then I commit the pull with a commit number [c2] and pushed to server. But after the pull the project crashes often, so I decided to rollback the pull:

```
git checkout [c1]
```

Then I worked on [c1] and made 3 commits but didn't push to server. This evening when I tried to push the last commit [c5] to server it kept saying "Everything up to date" but the server branch always stays at [c2]. I did:

```
git branch
```

on my side and found I am at (no branch). Then I did a

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

Then I see the newbranch replaced (no branch). Then I did

```
git push origin newbranch
```

Finally pushed to the server. However I don't know what happened during these commands? Thanks!

Comment: Please add your commit graph to your question so that people can see what happened. You can scramble the commit hashes and messages if you want. Run `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` and add the relevant output please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GIT you should be on a branch to push some changes.

> **What happened ?**

It is all because of the below command.

"**git checkout [c1]**"

Lets say at start you were on branch **B1** and HEAD pointing to commit **[c2]**. If you checkout a commit sha directly, it puts you into a "detached head" state, which basically just means that the current sha that your working copy has checked out, doesn't have a branch pointing at it. And now you have commited 3 more commits(which were not on any branch). So, the only way to save you work is attaching your head to some branch. that is what you did by using command "**git checkout -b newbranch**"

> **What could have been done?**

instead of checking out the commit [C1] directly,

**Option1**

If you don't need the changes of commit [c2], you could have reverted the [C2] by using "**git revert [c2]**"

**Option2**

If you don't need the changes of commit [c2] and you want remove it from git history as well then, you could have reverted the [C2] by using "**git reset --hard HEAD^**" and force pushed it using "**git push -f**"

Answer (score 1):

Most likely its because you missed the -u option (to track upstream branch) on your git push. It should have been

```
git push -u origin newbranch.
```

See this SO link for more details:
[How do you make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch/2286030#2286030)